# Will vs2012 support edit-continue for code with lambdas

Tags: visual-studio, lambda

To simply repeat the title of this question... Will vs2012 support edit and continue for code with lambdas? Although this is more of a "tool" question, it is something of high concern (I think) to a lot of us here. Does anyone know, or better yet, have a link?

Comment: There is no product named "vs2012", your question requires a time machine.  Don't count on it.

Comment: @HansPassant, now there *is* a VS2012... James's guess was correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, VS2012 RC now supports edit and continue for methods that contain lambda expressions. I just realized that today. Note that you can't modify the lambda expression itself, but you can modify everything else in the method body.

Comment: I've been using VS2012 for a while now and, unless i'm doing something wrong, still no edit and continue anywhere within a method with a lambda.

Comment: @James, I just tried again and I can confirm it works. As I mentioned in my answer, you can't modify the lambda itself (or anything that affects it), but you can edit the rest of the method. Also, keep in mind that E&C still doesn't work in x64. It might be the reason why it's not working for you. I'm not sure if it works with all kinds of applications (I only tried in desktop apps, not web on Windows Store apps).